# Duda Aritmética de Punteros

Tags: c

Estoy realizando tipos test para un examen y me he encontrado con el siguiente ejercicio:

[image: Imagen]

**Enunciado**:

Donde la función `crearRegistrosRef()` crea un vector de punteros a registro `tipoEmpleado`, y en cada celda de dicho vector almacena la dirección de memoria del primer byte de un bloque de memoria reservado dinámicamente de tamaño suficiente para almacenar un registro del tipo tipoEmpleado, y la función copiarRegistro() copia el contenido del registro referenciado por origen en el registro referenciado por destino devolviendo un valor entero indicando si ha tenido éxito o no.
Indicar cuál de las siguientes NO es una invocación correcta a esta última función:

- (A)  `errNum = copiarRegistro(empleados[12], &unEmpleado);`
- (B)  `errNum = copiarRegistro(&(*empleados[12]), &unEmpleado);`
- (C)  `errNum = copiarRegistro(&empleados[12], &unEmpleado);`
- (D)  `errNum = copiarRegistro(*(empleados+12), &unEmpleado);`

Yo votaría por la C como incorrecta, pero mi duda es si en la B, al haber un &, se anularía el * o si eso no se podría hacer en C. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pues a primera vista yo diría que la C es la única correcta. A y D son equivalentes y en ambos casos estás pasando como primer parámetro un registro, en lugar de la direciión de uno. B está directamente mal porque no puedes desreferenciar un elemento del array, ya que esos elementos no son punteros.